# Last margin / padding collapsing in flexbox / grid layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a list of items that I'm trying to arrange into a scrollable horizontal layout with flexbox.

Each item in the container has a margin left and right, but the right margin of the last item is being collapsed.

Is there a way to stop this happening, or a good workaround?

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  background: orange;
}
ul li {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 90px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 85):

### Potential Problem #1

The last margin is not being collapsed. It's being ignored.

The `overflow` property applies only to **content**. It doesn't apply to padding or margins.

Here's what it says in the spec:

> [**11.1.1 Overflow: the `overflow`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visufx.html#overflow)
>
> This property specifies whether content of a block container element
>   is clipped when it overflows the element's box.

Now let's take a look at the [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html):

[image]

<sup>source: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html)</sup>

The `overflow` property is limited to the content box area. If the content overflows its container, then `overflow` applies. But `overflow` doesn't enter into the padding or margin areas (unless, of course, there is more content that follows).

---

### Potential Problem #2

The problem with Potential Problem #1 is that it appears to fall apart outside of a flex or grid formatting context. For example, in a standard block layout, the last margin doesn't appear to collapse. So maybe `overflow` is permitted to cover margins / paddings, regardless of what it says in the spec.

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  background: orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <span>Item 4</span>
</div>
```

Hence, maybe the problem is instead related to elements that are "over-constrained".

> [**10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal
>   flow**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth)
>
> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other
>   properties:
>
> `margin-left` + `border-left-width` + `padding-left` + `width` +
>   `padding-right` + `border-right-width` + `margin-right` = width of
>   containing block
>
> If `width` is not `auto` and `border-left-width` + `padding-left` +
>   `width` + `padding-right` + `border-right-width` (plus any of
>   `margin-left` or `margin-right` that are not `auto`) is larger than
>   the width of the containing block, then any `auto` values for
>   `margin-left` or `margin-right` are, for the following rules, treated
>   as zero.
>
> ***If all of the above have a computed value other than `auto`, the values are said to be "over-constrained" and one of the used values
>   will have to be different from its computed value. If the `direction`
>   property of the containing block has the value `ltr`, the specified
>   value of `margin-right` is ignored and the value is calculated so as
>   to make the equality true.*** If the value of `direction` is `rtl`,
>   this happens to `margin-left` instead
>
> (emphasis added)

So, according to the [CSS Visual Formatting Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html), elements may be "over-constrained" and, as a result, a right margin gets tossed out.

---

### Potential Workarounds

Instead of margin or padding, use a right **border** on the last element:

```
li:last-child {
  border-right: 30px solid orange;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px; /* adjusted for demo */
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  background: orange;
}
ul li {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 90px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
li:last-child {
  border-right: 30px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Another solution uses a **pseudo-elements** instead of margins or padding.

Pseudo-elements on a flex container are rendered as flex items. The first item in the container is `::before` and last item is `::after`.

```
ul::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px; /* adjusted for demo */
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  background: orange;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0 30px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 90px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
ul::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}

ul::before {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: **Note:** If you're using definite `width` on each element and add the `border-right` to last element, this will impact the visible width of that element as border is part of the element in case of `border-box` is of box-sizing. Change the *box-sizing* to default or `content-box`.

Comment: `border-left: 10vw solid transparent;` solved all my troubles, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is not the margin in itself. It's the scroll bar dimensioning only the visible content of the element.

One hack to solve it would be to create a visible element that occupies the margin

This solution handles this using a pseudo on the last child

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  background: orange;
}
ul li {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 90px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-basis: auto;
  position: relative;
}
li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class"container">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set `width` and `overflow` on the `div` container, and set `display: inline-flex` rather than `flex` on the `ul`, so that the size of the flex box will be calculated based on the items inside, and all padding and margin will apply without any issues.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  background: orange;
}

.container li {
  padding: 60px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Oct 2023 it looks like you can fix this problem without pseudo elements by using a combination of `gap` and `padding` on the parent element instead of `margin`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  background: orange;
  /* ADD THIS */
  gap: 60px;
  padding: 0 60px;
}
ul li {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 90px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

See the solution. I remove `white-space`, `flex-basis`  and `margin`, to provide you a pure flexbox solution.

It relays on `flex-flow: row`(horizontal), `justify-content: space-around` (your *margin*) and no more!! The `width` is changed to `1200px` since the padding of 90px set the total width of the boxes more than your 600px (defined in your snippet).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row ;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  background: orange;
}
ul li {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class"container">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: With that solution, the margin will collapse to 0 if the container is narrower than the combined widths of the list items so doesn't really fit my requirements. I also need to be able to specify the margin width of each item.

Comment: So you don't need flexbox. You need a normal layout. You can use display inline-block or floats, and white-space to avoid line break. But this requirements have nothing to do with flexbox (flexible boxes), and you don't need that flexible boxes, you need a fixed-fluid layout.

Comment: I'm using flexbox because I want to have consistent heights for elements. I'm also wrapping to different rows on larger viewports; the scroll is just for small screens. The overview of the spec I read mentions collapsing top and bottom margins, but not left and right. The left margin of the first item isn't collapsed, so I thought it odd that the RHS of the last item was. I appreciate your help, it's just not answering the question about the collapsing margin.

Comment: Don't worry. Each one knows what requirements needs for his project. I don't know all your requirements. So I wish you good luck, but I remove this answer since it's not what you want. The last margin here is working fine ;) In your code I think it's the problem of the total width, or the width of the elements. Each element's size is at least 200px with 60px margin, you have 4 elements, and the total width of the parent box is 600px. Simply it doesn't fit.