# CSS: margin-right and parent element

Tags: html, css

Is margin-right not calculated or taken into account in the following example? what happens when someone increases margin-right on **.box**? it has no effect. why?

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #9CF;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffd900;
  margin: 50px;
}
p {
  background: #EEA458;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga ipsam quibusdam pariatur animi doloremque libero sed odio asperiores aliquam, accusamus vel voluptas iusto labore ipsa aspernatur voluptates, blanditiis. Eaque rem sapiente officiis dolores
      incidunt assumenda natus reprehenderit quisquam, perspiciatis ab nostrum eligendi deserunt, pariatur, obcaecati fuga quos sunt nemo ullam!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is being changed so I don't understand the issue unless you are only following the width of the `<p>` element.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38993170/3597276

Answer (score 3):

You have a `margin: 50px` declaration, which applies margins on all sides, as well as a `width: 300px` declaration. The values are over-constrained — since you can't expect a 300-pixel wide box to only have 50-pixel horizontal margins in a containing block whose width is greater than 300 + 50 + 50 pixels — which does indeed result in [the specified value of margin-right being ignored](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#blockwidth) (in the typical LTR writing mode).

Comment: I think, I have problems with containing block and content block. Do you know any easy to follow tut?

Comment: It is ignored but `getComputedStyle(box).marginRight` still says `50px`

Comment: @Oriol: That's why the spec says "one of the used values will have to be different from its computed value".

Comment: @Oriol: ... I just remembered that getComputedStyle usually returns something close to the used value. Well, all I can say then is that's getComputedStyle for you.

Comment: @BoltClock `getComputedStyle` returns the resolved value, which in this case should be the used value. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the margin is getting collapsed. It **does** have a margin, but you cannot see. To make it visible, we need ti add the `overflow: hidden` to recalculate and show up the margin.

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #9CF;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffd900;
  margin: 50px;
}
p {
  background: #EEA458;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga ipsam quibusdam pariatur animi doloremque libero sed odio asperiores aliquam, accusamus vel voluptas iusto labore ipsa aspernatur voluptates, blanditiis. Eaque rem sapiente officiis dolores
      incidunt assumenda natus reprehenderit quisquam, perspiciatis ab nostrum eligendi deserunt, pariatur, obcaecati fuga quos sunt nemo ullam!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

After applying `overflow: hidden` to the parent, you could see the top and bottom margins too.

**And since your `margin-right: 50px;` is lesser than `150px` of the space on the right**, you cannot see the right margins.

This is the current box model of the `.box`:

[image: box-model]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background of `.box` to be visible, use `padding` instead of `margin`:

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #9CF;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ffd900;
  padding: 50px;
}

p {
  background: #EEA458;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga ipsam quibusdam pariatur animi doloremque libero sed odio asperiores aliquam, accusamus vel voluptas iusto labore ipsa aspernatur voluptates, blanditiis. Eaque rem sapiente officiis dolores
      incidunt assumenda natus reprehenderit quisquam, perspiciatis ab nostrum eligendi deserunt, pariatur, obcaecati fuga quos sunt nemo ullam!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude, my question is about margin-right being ignored!

Comment: Yes, acknowledged - but I was trying to work out what you might mean by that. If you have given the parent container an explicit width, you can then give the child container any sort of right-hand margin, but it's not going to be apparent in any meaningful way when you refer to the visible (explicitly-stated) width of the parent container.