# Background color cuts off at viewport edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a row of divs that do not wrap and is scrollable with the regular page scrollbar (horizontal and vertical).

Only problem with my solution below is that the `background-color` (and right padding) of the row are not shown if I scroll to the right.

Requirements:

- I don't want scrollbars in the rows, only want to see a (horizontal and vertical) page scrollbar
- The background color of the rows are going to the end of the row (not like in the demo)
- Don't use a fixed width, because the width depends on the number of columns and they may grow in the future.

It's ok to use flexbox, etc.

```css
.row {
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #AAA;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.column:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/paulq/pen/gWpmWG (where the width is flexible now due container size something like this?)

Comment: You don't have a horizontal scrollbar now. I'm looking for a solution with a horizontal scrollbar (thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [@Michael_B's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441600/2827823) well explained answer, another solution would be to use `display: inline-block` on the `row`, which, in opposite to `block`, grows with its content.

As you can't set a width on the `row` (will stop it from growing with content), you need to use viewport units (or any other unit other than percent) when setting the width and margin on the `column`, so with the given markup, where the `row` is set to take full width of the viewport, this might be a viable option.

```css
.row {
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #AAA;
}
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50vw;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 5vw;
}
.column:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.item:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A block element by default extends to 100% width of its parent.

In your layout, that is exactly what is happening. The `background-color` on `.row` is covering the full with of its parent, `body`. Any overflow would not be included.

Therefore, instead of putting the background color on each `.row` element, put it on `body`.

Add this to your code:

```
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}
```

---

The collapsing right padding appears to be caused by the element being "over-constrained". When this happens, the right margin / padding is ignored.

You can read more about that here: [How can I stop the last margin collapsing in flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38993170/3597276)

To fix the problem in your layout, try using a transparent border instead of padding.

Add this to your code:

```
.column:last-child {
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

---

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  white-space: normal;
}

.column + .column {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.column:last-child {
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1bu5uu5/1/)

Comment: Plus 1...and, IMHO, the linked _pseudo fix `::after { content: ""; flex: 0 0 30px; }`_ feels less intrusive than a transparent border and enables the `column`'s to be fully styled

Comment: @LGSon, I agree that the flex pseudo element is a cleaner and nicer solution. But since the original code wasn't in flex layout, I didn't pursue flex methods with much intensity.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot put the backgroundcolor to the body, because I wanted to create a zebra effect.

@LGSon gave me the solution I was looking for by using inline-block for the rows

Comment: You should add the zebra-striping to your list of requirements.