# Why is content overflowing in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am experiencing some behavior that I don't understand. When I set up a list of badges with a max-height on the list and margin on the list items then the content for the list items overflows their containers proportionally to the margin.

```css
.badgers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.badge, .title, .location, .timestamp {
  display: flex;
}

.badge {
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="badgers">
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title 2</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title 3</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove the margin then there is no overflow.

```css
.badgers {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.badge, .title, .location, .timestamp {
  display: flex;
}

.badge {
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="badgers">
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title 2</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title 3</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I change the wrapper to `display: block` and leave the margin then the list looks like what I want.

```css
.badgers {
  max-height: 10em;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.badge, .title, .location, .timestamp {
  display: flex;
}

.badge {
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="badgers">
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title 2</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
  <div class="badge">
      <span class="title">Title 3</span>
      <span class="location">Location</span>
      <span class="timestamp">Timestamp</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**So why does the content overflow when the list is `display: flex; flex-direction: column` but not when it is `display: block`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, flex items are set to `flex-shrink: 1` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)).

This means they can shrink to avoid overflowing the container.

Disable this feature. Make your flex items `flex-shrink: 0`.

---

**UPDATE** (based on comments):

- **It doesn't work in Firefox.**

  Actually, the solution above was tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. It works ([fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qw2pv0nd/)).
- **It still works in Firefox when `flex-shrink: 0` is removed.**

  This is because in Firefox another default setting is in play: `min-height: auto`. This means that flex items can't shrink below the height of their content. Chrome does an "intervention" on this, which overrides the spec setting.

  See this post for a full explanation: [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

  The `flex-shrink: 0` approach is a solid cross-browser solution.
- **The margin on the last item collapses.**

  This likely happens because the containing block is "over-constrained".

  See this post for a full explanation and solutions: [Last margin / padding collapsing in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38993170/3597276)

Comment: Thanks! I think that I can just put it on `.badge` and it will make room for its children so they wont shrink.

Comment: @dippas, I tested in current Chrome, FF and Edge. It worked in all. https://jsfiddle.net/qw2pv0nd/

Comment: Same here, but when I removed `flex-shrink: 0;` in FF it still worked. Same for IE and Edge. Seems to be a chrome only issue?

Comment: @Michael_B still the same output, if I understood OP, he wants space(`margin`) in last item  showing and it doesn't in FF https://i.imgur.com/WotTOS5.png

Comment: @dippas The margin shows up for me in FF, IE, and Edge without the flex-shrink. Even adding `flex-shrink: 1` doesn't make it "break" in those browsers.

Comment: @bygrace this is how I see it with or without `flex-shrink: 0`  in FF https://i.imgur.com/N7gwxwI.png

Comment: @dippas I see your point. I actually don't want the margin on the top or bottom but didn't put that in the example. The example is setup so that I would expect it to be there. So thank you for pointing that out!