# Why do Chrome and Firefox show different flex layout results?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

When there is only one row of "flex items", Chrome and Firefox show different results. When there is more than one line(wrap), Chrome and Firefox show the same result!

So why is this happening? Is that a bug, or is there some "default value" or difference that I am missing?

```css
body{
    background-color: teal;
}

.flexContainer{
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 300px;
}
.flexItem{
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.flexContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.flexItem{ 
    flex: 0 1 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="flexItem">1111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="flexItem">2222<br/>2222</div>
    <div class="flexItem">3333<br/>3333<br/>3333</div>
    <div class="flexItem">4444444444444444444</div>
</div>
```

Comment: because `align-content` it is still a draft . https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property If i understand , for a single line, it should not be applied and chrome would do what expected unless a prefix is needed ... indeed not clear what to expect, but rule is not a candidate either ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Source of the Problem

Here is the source of the problem:

```
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: flex-start; <-- problem
}
```

---

### Background

The [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content) property controls the cross-axis alignment of *flex lines* within the flex container. Think of flex lines as the rows or columns (depending on [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)) in which flex items live. Put another way, `align-content` distributes the space between and around flex lines, packing them to the top, bottom, center, etc. (see the [full list of values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)).

Because `align-content` distributes space *between and around* flex lines, it can only work on *multi-line* flex containers. (A single-line extends across the full cross-axis length of the container leaving no free space for `align-content` to work.)

Obviously, a multi-line container is a container with more than one line (flex items have wrapped). Technically, however, a multi-line container is simply a container with [`flex-wrap: wrap` or `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) (regardless of whether flex items have wrapped, or even exist).

Same concept applies to a single-line flex container, which is a container with `flex-wrap: nowrap`. The `align-content` property has no effect in `nowrap` containers, as discussed above.

> [**§ 8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
> property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within
> the flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis,
> similar to how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the
> main-axis. **Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex
> container**.
>
> [**§ 6. Flex
> Lines**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-lines)
>
> Flex items in a flex container are laid out and aligned within *flex
> lines*, hypothetical containers used for grouping and alignment by the
> layout algorithm. A flex container can be either single-line or
> multi-line, depending on the `flex-wrap` property:
>
> - A *single-line flex container* (i.e. one with `flex-wrap: nowrap`) lays out all of its children in a single line, even if that would
>   cause its contents to overflow.
> - A *multi-line flex container* (i.e. one with `flex-wrap: wrap` or `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`) breaks its flex items across multiple lines, similar to how text is broken onto a new line when it gets too wide to fit on the existing line.

---

### The Discrepancy between Chrome and Firefox / Edge

Looking again at your code:

```css
body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.flexContainer {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
}

.flexItem {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flexItem {
  flex: 0 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="flexItem">1111111111111111111</div>
  <div class="flexItem">2222<br/>2222</div>
  <div class="flexItem">3333<br/>3333<br/>3333</div>
  <div class="flexItem">4444444444444444444</div>
</div>
```

Notice three things:

(1) There is no actual wrapping. All four items exist on one line. The flex container has one line.

(2) The `flex-wrap` property is set to `wrap` (in the `flex-flow` shorthand).

(3) The `align-content` property is set to `flex-start`.

Let's break this down.

Because there is only a single line in the flex container, Chrome is ignoring `align-content`. As written in the specification (see above):

> The `align-content` property *has no effect on a single-line flex container*.

So this is Chrome's interpretation. If there is an actual single line, then ignore `align-content`.

Switch between `wrap` and `nowrap` in Chrome. There's no difference.

On the other hand, because the container is set to `flex-wrap: wrap`, this technically creates a multi-line flex container, as far as Firefox and Edge are concerned. The actual wrapping or existence of flex items is irrelevant.

As written in the specification (see above):

> *A multi-line flex container (i.e. one with `flex-wrap: wrap` or `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`) breaks its flex items across multiple lines...*

Switch between `wrap` and `nowrap` in Firefox and Edge. There's a difference.

So each browser has it's own way of implementing this rendering behavior.

---

### Standards Compliance

In terms of adherence to the specification, I would say that Firefox and Edge are at full compliance. They seem to adhere most closely to the wording in the spec.

However, I wouldn't characterize Chrome's behavior as a "bug". What they've done is more likely an [**intervention**](https://github.com/WICG/interventions).

> An intervention is when a user agent decides to deviate slightly from a standardized behavior in order to provide a greatly enhanced user experience.

Interventions appear to be standard practice at Chrome. Examples:

- [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
- [flex-shrink discrepancy between Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49575838/3597276)
- [Why are percentage heights working on children when the parent has no height defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47521718/3597276)
- [pseudo element not aligning at top left corner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45039016/3597276)
- [Google Chrome viewport-anchored expand direction with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44826446/3597276)
- [How to make images stay within the rows of a css grid container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46303488/3597276)
- [Flex items overlapping in Chrome and IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48294014/3597276)
- [Why is content overflowing in flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47834329/3597276)
- [Prevent flex item from exceeding parent height and make scroll bar work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52487743/3597276)
- [Prevent flex item from exceeding parent height and make scroll bar work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52487743/3597276)
- [Vertical spacing difference in Chrome v Firefox using flexbox column wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68327640/3597276)

---

### More Information

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Comment: Chrome has zero _flexbox-specific_ interventions. If you have a case where Chrome and Firefox render a flexbox differently and can't find an existing relevant bug, please file a new one at https://crbug.com/new with a minimal reproduction case.

Comment: I wanted to give the Chrome team the benefit of the doubt. There are so many cases (some listed above) where Chrome deviates from the flexbox spec, that I assumed they were interventions. I didn't think they would be all bugs.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why Firefox comes out ahead of Chrome almost all of the time in terms of adherence to the flexbox standard.

Comment: There are historical reasons that are best discussed IRL. But we're specifically working on cross-browser flex spec adherence this year in conjunction with the Firefox team and some open source contributors who work on Webkit. You can see our progress at https://wpt.fyi/compat2021?feature=css-flexbox