# Issue with vertical centering

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use a `relative div` to fill it up with `inline-block`-elements aligned next to each other that all got the same width & same height *(= squares)*.

So if there are `n` elements the `relative div` should get scrollable in x-direction. This is working so far as you can see in the example code below:

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4%;
  margin: 0% 3%;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But now I'd like the `item`-elements *(yellow squares)* to vertical align into the `red parent-div` *(relative div)* so that the distance from top to center and from bottom to center is identical. Please have a look at this image:

[image]

**Note**: I do not want to change the hierarchy *(keep the parent elem relative & the outer elem absolute, etc...)*

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For further reference, see [Centering in CSS: A Complete Guide @ CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

Comment: @Temani Afif. For real? You marked a flex-box using answer as correct answer for this question? Had a look at **"keep the parent elem relative & the outer elem absolute, etc..."**. So `relative != flex`.

Comment: @Asker i added the flexbox solution as the second dup ;) and i can add many more if you want ... flexbox is an alternative to be considered for future reader

Comment: now you have all the duplicate related to centring, am limited to 5 but i can still add more.

Comment: Flex does not affect relative/absolute position values.

Comment: ... So if it makes you happy Temani, do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).
See [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Below, [`align-items:center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items):

> ... defines how the browser distributes space between and around flex items along the cross-axis of their container.

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 4%;
  margin: 0 3%;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 0 0 4%;
  margin: 0 3%;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't changed the hierarchy.

Comment: Ok. I see your right. Thanks for your solution. But theres a problem anyway. Please have a look what happens if there are only a few (like 2x) items. The should also get centered horizontal. But they aren't -  because one of the items is on the left - the other one on the right bound of the red area. So would you be so kind to edit your solution? Greetings, Tom **Edit**: Using `justify-content: center;` will move the most left item out of the scollable div bounds!

Comment: I changed `justify-content` from `space-between` to `center`. However, the last child's right margin seems to be truncated, I believe because the containing block is "over-constrained". Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution. See [Last margin / padding collapsing in flexbox / grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993170/last-margin-padding-collapsing-in-flexbox-grid-layout/38997047#38997047).

Comment: I would say the [answer from Franklin Pious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50050412/924299) is simpler in your situation. But I find that solution also truncates the margin, this time the left margin of the first child. [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/gnqkj607/).¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. If interested, see [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454533/cant-scroll-to-top-of-flex-item-that-is-overflowing-container) for an explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Without using css flex.

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}

.item {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4%;
  margin: 0% 3%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: relative;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the .parent element this code and it should work:
(you can keep the code that you've already wrote)

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
```

Comment: But you aren't changing the hierarchy, the only thing that changes is the display property.

Comment: You're getting it wrong. The **display** property changes to **flex**. The **position** stays **relative**

Comment: Ok. Thanks - I had another look at the docs & they told me- your right!

Comment: No problem, ambiguities can happen :). Please tick then his and my anwsers if they worked for you :)