# CSS Grid with fixed size scrolling: How to solve issue where bottom margin/padding isn't shown?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, css-grid

**EDIT**:

So I saw the duplicate link that was pointed to, and in my opinion, this question is to solve issues where you have given a fixed size (fixed width or fixed height).

The original question's solution is more about fixing the container using hacky methods. I decided to make a different approach of fixing it, while also fixing my own issue laid out in this question.

---

In CSS, when working with `display: grid` and `fixed height`, with `overflow: auto` turned on, you may get this kind of layout, shown below:

```css
.scroll {
  overflow:  auto;
  background-color: #bbddee;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  height: 420px;
}

.itemContainer {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.itemTitle {
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.itemLink {
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="retailerContent" class="tab-pane fade in active show">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div id="retailerOffersContainer" class="container">

      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When this happens, there is an issue where there are no paddings/margins down at the very bottom of the scroll list. How should the HTML and CSS be modified, so the bottom padding/margin would show up inside a scrollable CSS grid layout?

Comment: @Michael_B It seems like a possible duplicate, but my answer was mainly focused on stretching the boundaries of the container using the size of the elements. Maybe that's just one of many?

Comment: @Michael_B I did provide an explanation, just below the code snippet. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993170/last-margin-padding-collapsing-in-flexbox-grid-layout

Comment: A duplicate question is for the same initial issue and for different answer ... so you question is the same as the other if we consider the issue

Comment: Thank you to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my fix for when I was using CSS Grids:

```
/* Fix scrollbar removing padding-bottom */
@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
  .container::after {
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    margin: calc(var(--padding) - var(--gap));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution (probably one of many) that shows how to fix the issue of missing bottom padding/margin in a fixed height `div` with `display: grid`:

```css
.container {
 padding: 10px;
 display: grid;
 grid-row-gap: 10px;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;
 width: 100%;
 }
 
 .itemContainer {
 border: 1px solid #efefef;
 background-color: #fff;
 max-height: 100%;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 height: 100%;
 }
 
 .itemTitle {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 line-height: 20px;
 }
 
 .itemLink {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 line-height: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="retailerContent" class="tab-pane fade in active show">
  <div style="height: 420px;background-color: #bbddee;">
    <div id="retailerOffersContainer" class="container">

      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="itemTitle">15% Off Room Essentials Cubes &amp; Bins</div>
        <div class="itemLink"><a>Get Offer&nbsp;&gt;</a></div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main difference here is:

- Grid container should not specify a height property. Allow the grid to conform to the height of the total contents and the grid gaps automatically.
- Instead, make the elements inside the grid container have a max height, defined by the inner contents of said elements.

This will stretch the grid container, without the grid element contents spilling over and outside of the grid container.

Comment: If I'm wrong, please tell me what needs to be fixed, so that I can learn from your criticisms. Thanks.

Comment: sorry but this has absolutely nothing to do with CSS-grid, it's a simply overflow issue with padding that we can easily adjust. There is a ton of question dealing with this

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see. If it's an overflow issue with padding, what's the proper way to adjust it, so the original issue is fixed? Thanks.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah, that's something I didn't know before. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @TemaniAfif CSS-Grid does play a part because my fix has to do extra work for CSS Grid/Flux gaps. Otherwise your new padding is the size of your gaps. Easy to miss if your gaps and padding are the same.