# Add space before and after first and last grid items

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

My question is identical to this [question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165983/css-grid-horizontal-scroll-adding-space-before-and-after-scrolled-items) but the given solution does not work.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/gEKOYV) of what I'm working with.

I've tried two different approaches, both of which are almost correct but not quite:

***1. Applying `::before` and `::after` psuedo classes to first and last grid items***

Unfortunately when I add `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties to the first and last grid item respectively, it adds the space to the grid items as if it were `padding` space and not `margin` space, otherwise this works fine.

***2. Applying `::before` and `::after` psuedo classes to grid container***

It will not allow me to manipulate the `width` of `::before`. For some reason the `width` property of `::before` does not take effect. Notably, it seems as if the value of its `width` is the same `width` value as any given grid item.

I noticed another peculiarity, which is ultimately irrelevant, with this approach too. If I apply a `width` to `::after`, `grid-gap` also gets applied as if it is inserting an invisible grid item.

```css
:root {
  --gap: 25px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0
}

#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: calc(calc(100% - calc(var(--gap) * 2)) / 1.5);
  border: solid red 1px;
}

/* second approach */
#c::before {
  content: '';
  width: var(--gap);
}

#c::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px; /* works out to about 25px or var(--gap) */
}

.i {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
}

/* first approach */
/*
.i:first-child::before {
  content: '';
  margin-left: var(--gap);
}

.i:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  margin-right: var(--gap);
}
*/

.i:nth-child(odd) {
  background: skyblue;
}

.i:nth-child(even) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id='c'>
  <div class='i'>1</div>
  <div class='i'>2</div>
  <div class='i'>3</div>
  <div class='i'>4</div>
  <div class='i'>5</div>
  <div class='i'>6</div>
  <div class='i'>7</div>
  <div class='i'>8</div>
  <div class='i'>9</div>
  <div class='i'>10</div>
  <div class='i'>11</div>
  <div class='i'>12</div>
  <div class='i'>13</div>
  <div class='i'>14</div>
  <div class='i'>15</div>
  <div class='i'>16</div>
  <div class='i'>17</div>
  <div class='i'>18</div>
  <div class='i'>19</div>
  <div class='i'>20</div>
  <div class='i'>21</div>
  <div class='i'>22</div>
  <div class='i'>23</div>
  <div class='i'>24</div>
</div>
```

Does anybody have any idea why this stuff is happening?

**How can I change the width of `::before`?**

Comment: the before element is simply a grid element so it will take the same width defined for the other element (note that element is inside a grid track so its width is defined inside another hidden wrapper)

Comment: @TemaniAfif but why will it allow me to manipulate the `width` of `::after` which also seems to be a grid element? and how can i change the width of `::before`?

Comment: not sure about this one something to do with overflow probably

Comment: @TemaniAfif i would suspect it prolly has something to do with `auto-flow` and `auto-columns` and not overflow?

Comment: i am not really sure, I will try to see more .. but technically (per my understanding) it should have the same width as the other. I am probably missing something trivial

Comment: yes it's for sure overflow. The track is having the correct width but overflow is not considering the width of the track but only the element width. Basically `after` is behaving the same as `before` but its track is overflowing and not counted inside the scrolling area.

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh wow. i wonder if thats considered a "bug" or if theyll end up changing that within the browser implementation of css3 grids??

Comment: or probably it's by design, I am trying to find if there is anything describing this in the spec

Comment: @TemaniAfif not very user friendly if it is by design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea to change the width of before is to define a column template like below that will force the width of the first element only then the other will follow the `grid-auto-columns`. Basically we define an explicit grid with 1 column then the browser will add more column as needed to create the implicit grid:

```css
:root {
  --gap: 25px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0
}

#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns:1px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: calc(calc(100% - calc(var(--gap) * 2)) / 1.5);
  border: solid red 1px;
}

/* second approach */
#c::before {
  content: '';
}

#c::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px; /* works out to about 25px or var(--gap) */
}

.i {
  /*width: 100%; not needed*/
  height: 25px;
  /*display: inline-block; not needed*/
}

.i:nth-child(odd) {
  background: skyblue;
}

.i:nth-child(even) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id='c'>
  <div class='i'>1</div>
  <div class='i'>2</div>
  <div class='i'>3</div>
  <div class='i'>4</div>
  <div class='i'>5</div>
  <div class='i'>6</div>
  <div class='i'>7</div>
  <div class='i'>8</div>
  <div class='i'>9</div>
  <div class='i'>10</div>
  <div class='i'>11</div>
  <div class='i'>12</div>
  <div class='i'>13</div>
  <div class='i'>14</div>
  <div class='i'>15</div>
  <div class='i'>16</div>
  <div class='i'>17</div>
  <div class='i'>18</div>
  <div class='i'>19</div>
  <div class='i'>20</div>
  <div class='i'>21</div>
  <div class='i'>22</div>
  <div class='i'>23</div>
  <div class='i'>24</div>
</div>
```

Comment: brilliant <3333

Comment: @Anthony yes, any value will do it ;) You can also try `auto` and `1fr` they will do the same

Answer (score 1):

This is [another one of those instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55064488/3597276) where flexbox may provide a simpler, easier and more effective solution that grid.

```css
:root {
  --gap: 25px;
}

#c {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.i {
  height: 25px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(calc(100% - calc(var(--gap) * 2)) / 1.5); /* fg, fs, fb */
}

#c::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 0 var(--gap);
}

.i {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#c::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 0 calc(var(--gap) - 20px); /* gap less margin */
}

.i:nth-child(odd)  { background: skyblue; }
.i:nth-child(even) { background: pink; }
body               { margin: 0; }
*                  { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div id='c'>
  <div class='i'>1</div>
  <div class='i'>2</div>
  <div class='i'>3</div>
  <div class='i'>4</div>
  <div class='i'>5</div>
  <div class='i'>6</div>
  <div class='i'>7</div>
  <div class='i'>8</div>
  <div class='i'>9</div>
  <div class='i'>10</div>
  <div class='i'>11</div>
  <div class='i'>12</div>
  <div class='i'>13</div>
  <div class='i'>14</div>
  <div class='i'>15</div>
  <div class='i'>16</div>
  <div class='i'>17</div>
  <div class='i'>18</div>
  <div class='i'>19</div>
  <div class='i'>20</div>
  <div class='i'>21</div>
  <div class='i'>22</div>
  <div class='i'>23</div>
  <div class='i'>24</div>
</div>
```

You may also want to consider a **transparent border** for start- and end-side spacing. [Last margin / padding collapsing in flexbox / grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38993170/3597276)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but grid is far superior in this situation due to `grid-gap`. and everything is working perfectly now. the problem with flex is that u always have to add margin or padding and continually adjust them

Comment: Right. In this situation. But maybe not in others. That's why I posted the answer. Plus, the [`gap` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#gap-shorthand) is expected to be available in flex containers.

Comment: thats what i figured, but ive found that in most situations for me personally grid is far superior to flex. ***expected*** to be available in flex containers? when?

Comment: I would guess before the end of this year, but I have no inside information.

Comment: And Grid is a superior technology. But [flex still has advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55064488/3597276).

Comment: definitely!! im sure flex still has its moments, but theyre few and far between now imo.