# widths and centering with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am trying to create a sort of *text carousel*. 
Heres a sketch of what I want to do: [image: card image]

I have a card and I might have multiple of them.
If there's **one** I just need it to be neatly centered both vertically and horizontally.
If there's **two** then try to put them next to one another.
**But** if there's more than there can be fit on the screen, then I just want the last one to *overflow* off

**All the cards need to retain the same size**

**This is what I have tried:**

**Firstly** I tried using `align-items: flex-start`
 http://jsfiddle.net/7pdmeh6v/

This works with the logic but the problems are that if I had one item it wouldn't be centered and here I can't change the width.

**Secondly** I tried using `align-items: center`
 http://jsfiddle.net/hr8ya9fg/

Logic works **but**
 This cuts off the top of the cards and also doesn't let me change
 the size of the cards.

**Thirdly** I removed `align-items` and just left `justify-content: center` http://jsfiddle.net/6hdzamq5/

which works with the logic but still doesn't let me change the size of the cards AND also I noticed here that it completely disregards margins and paddings

**TLDR:**
 Flex-box doesn't seem to let me edit the size on any occasion without another problem occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of initial observations:

- In a row-direction flex container, which is what you're using, the `align-*` properties control vertical, not horizontal, space and positioning. So I'm not sure how you plan to solve your horizontal scroll problem using `align-items`.
- The initial value of the `flex-shrink` property is `1`. This means that flex items will shrink in order to stay within the bounds of the container. So when you tell your flex items to be `width: 500px`, that is not a fixed length. The items can shrink. Add `flex-shrink: 0` to disable flex shrink and make the items inflexible.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

.box {
  width: 500px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* toggle between 1 and 0 to see the differences */
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.box ~ .box {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that the last margin / padding collapses. That issue is explained here:

- [Last margin / padding collapsing in flexbox / grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38993170/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you looking into `flex` property which is a shorthand for `flex-shrink`, `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` properties. It would help you to define behavior of your flex-items. (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

See the snippet below:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 320px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #9a6;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas corporis et nesciunt esse quas eos illum, facere voluptate, iure officiis.
  </div>
</div>
```