# Right margin not showing with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, margin

In my mobile view, I have a horizontal scroll that holds three divs (like cards).  The horizontal scroll works perfectly, however, the last div's right margin is not showing. It should show 6px.  All three divs have `margin-left: 6px` and `margin-right: 6px;`

Here's the left margin showing correctly:

[image]

Here's the right margin not showing at all:

[image]

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* Html */
  html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  /* Cards */
  .mobile-card-container>.row {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  .mobile-card-container {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .card-background {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 1px rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.1);
    margin-left: 6px !important;
    margin-right: 6px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<html>

<body>


  <!-- Simulaciones Default -->
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Mobile Card Container -->
    <div class="col-12 mobile-card-container container-fluid" style="border: 1px solid;">
      <div class="row flex-nowrap flex-sm-wrap" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <!-- Card 1  -->
        <div class="col-10 card-background simulacion mx-auto">
          Card 1
        </div>

        <!-- Card 2 -->
        <div class="col-10 card-background simulacion mx-auto">
          Card 2
        </div>

        <!-- Card 3 -->
        <div class="col-10 card-background simulacion mx-auto">
          Card 3
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /Mobile Card Container -->



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This post solved my problem. I basically added a `content` to my last div.

[Last margin / padding collapsing in flexbox / grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993170/last-margin-padding-collapsing-in-flexbox-grid-layout)