# Why is the last row of elements displaced in my css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I was testing scroll snapping and I noticed something about my grid.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, calc((100vw - 2rem) / 3 - ((100vw - 100%) / 3)));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, calc((90vh) - ((90vh - 100%))));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
  scroll-padding: 1rem;
}

.card {

  scroll-snap-align: start;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
  <li class="card"></li>
</ul>
```

I calculate column sizes by subtracting the outside padding from the viewport width(`(100vw - 2rem)`) and then subtracting the size of the vertical scrollbars(`(100vw - 100%)`). Same for rows only that i don't need to subtract the padding here for it to fit in the viewport.

If you scroll all the way to the end, you can see that there is no `padding-bottom` or `padding-right` visible.
If you inspect it, you can see that the last row of elements displaced by `1rem` upwards and `1rem` to the left. You can also see that the padding is behind the scrollbars.

Why is this happening?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38993170/3597276

Comment: Didn't get any of the non-hacky solutions to work from that one. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, though not super elegant.

```
.child:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 1px;
}
```

It looks like padding and margins are ignored in overflowing containers, so to add margin or padding to the right and bottom sides of an overflowing container you have to simulate it using a pseudo-element that the browser can't ignore.

Source: https://blog.alexandergottlieb.com/overflow-scroll-and-the-right-padding-problem-a-css-only-solution-6d442915b3f4