# How can I get the bottom margin of the last child in a scrolling flexbox parent to display?

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

In the interface below, the (parent) `.panel` (styled using `flex`) won't scroll below the bottom edge of the last (child) `.item` even though the last `.item` (like the all the others) should have a `margin-bottom` of `12px`.

That's what I'm trying to achieve:

**When I scroll down, I want to see the `12px` bottom margin of the last `.item`.**

Here's the interface:

```css
.interface {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 60px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(159, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.header,
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(159, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(15, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.header {
  top: 0;
}

.heading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

.credit {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.intro {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(127, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(15, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: calc(100vh - 180px);
  padding-top: 12px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1 30vw;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 12px;
  line-height: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(31, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(47, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 1px solid rgb(95, 0, 0);
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 906px) {

  .item {
    flex: 0 1 44vw;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {

  .item {
    flex: 0 1 96vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside class="interface">

<header class="header">
<h2 class="heading">Title</h2>
</header>

<p class="intro">Text-based introduction here.</p>

<div class="panel">
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 6</div>
<div class="item">Item 7</div>
<div class="item">Item 8</div>
<div class="item">Item 9</div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
<p class="credit">Credit</p>
</footer>

</aside>
```

**N.B.** Open the `Code Snippet` above to **Full page**.

Comment: I suppose you are testing on Firefox because in Chrome it's fine

Comment: Hah! Yes. I do all of my CSS design work on Firefox. I haven't tested it on Chrome yet.

Comment: It may have something to do with elements being "over-constrained". The pseudo element is one potential workaround (btw, you don't need to add `display: block`). You can also use a transparent bottom border. https://stackoverflow.com/q/38993170/3597276

Comment: I thought your `border-bottom` suggestion was inspired. Unfortunately (I just tried it) it won't work because the `12px` border displays beneath the right hand scroll bar.

Comment: Well then you still have the pseudo element. It's a hack, of course, but not a particularly nasty one. Just a minor workaround, in my view.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to solving this issue is to use an `::after` pseudo-element, like this:

```
.panel::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

This would re-create the `12px` bottom margin which isn't otherwise displaying.

This is a little hack-y, since the only reason to include the `::after` pseudo-element is as a *"helper"* - it's pretty much a `spacer GIF`. (But still much less obtrusive than a wrapper `<div>`.)

**Working Example of interface with `::after` pseudo-element:**

```css
.interface {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 60px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(159, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.header,
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(159, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(15, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.header {
  top: 0;
}

.heading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
}

.credit {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.intro {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(127, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(15, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: calc(100vh - 180px);
  padding-top: 12px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1 30vw;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 12px;
  line-height: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(31, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(47, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 1px solid rgb(95, 0, 0);
}

.panel::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: transparent;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 906px) {

  .item {
    flex: 0 1 44vw;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {

  .item {
    flex: 0 1 96vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside class="interface">

<header class="header">
<h2 class="heading">Title</h2>
</header>

<p class="intro">Text-based introduction here.</p>

<div class="panel">
<div class="item">Item 1</div>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
<div class="item">Item 3</div>
<div class="item">Item 4</div>
<div class="item">Item 5</div>
<div class="item">Item 6</div>
<div class="item">Item 7</div>
<div class="item">Item 8</div>
<div class="item">Item 9</div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
<p class="credit">Credit</p>
</footer>

</aside>
```

**N.B.** Open the `Code Snippet` above to **Full page**.