# CSS Grid padding right on the last item on horizontal scrolling with grid-auto-flow: column;

Tags: css, css-grid

Padding on the right does not show up on the right side of the last item. How do I make it to show up like the left of the first item.

*Padding left on the first item*
[image]

*Padding right on the last item(padding right is there but it does not give space to the right on the last item*
[image]

```css
.Container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.book-list {
  overflow: scroll;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  padding: 0 8px 16px 8px;
}

.book-list div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container book-list" }>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet for you. Please add your full css so we can work on it.

Comment: Are you set on making the Grid yourself in order to learn the basics behind a Grid, or is there any other reason why you're not allowing yourself to use either Flexbox or Bootstrap? These tools make Grids a worry of the past.

Comment: @dgknca added! @ Martin I found it easier and more flexible to use Grid than Flexbox or Bootstrap for myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Last margin / padding collapsing in flexbox / grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993170/last-margin-padding-collapsing-in-flexbox-grid-layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an extra empty element can fix this:

```css
.Container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.book-list {
  overflow: scroll;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  padding: 0 8px 16px 8px;
}
/* the fix */
.book-list::after {
  content:"";
  width:1px;
  margin-right:-1px;
}
/**/
.book-list div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container book-list" >
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book Name</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Book 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case it was necessary to add `height:1px` to fix, thank you!