# Why's my "flex" div not obeying the padding-right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this setup:

```css
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 200pt;
  margin-left: 7.5pt;
  margin-right: 7.5pt;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  border-radius: 10pt;
}

img:first-child {
  /*padding-left: 15pt;*/
  margin-left: auto;
}

img:last-child {
  /*padding-right: 100pt;*/
  margin-right: auto;
}

.images {
  background: orange;
  padding-left: 30pt;
  padding-right: 30pt;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-top: 15pt;
  margin-bottom: 15pt;
  height: 200pt;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.images::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ybdfu28a/

As you notice, the `images` div has a `padding-left` and `padding-right` of `30pt`. This seems to work fine on the left side but not on the right. The right side's image sticks to the edge when you scroll horizontally.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the linked question as border doesn't work in my case as I explained in the comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993170/last-margin-padding-collapsing-in-flexbox-grid-layout

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin that doesn't work well as I want the pics to scroll into the edges as shown in my initial example whereas using a border prevents that and the pics don't go into the edges on scrolling.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin pseudo elements removes all the left and right padding. In this: https://imgur.com/a/cbAujez notice how in first 2 pics of my original code, when scrolled, the pics scroll all the way to the left edges. But in 3rd pic when I use border, it doesn't go into the edges and orange is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your images div doesn't have a defined width, you can not place a padding on the right,

Here is a solution to add some space on the right of the last image

```
.images:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  padding-right: 30pt;
}
```

```css
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 200pt;
  margin-left: 7.5pt;
  margin-right: 7.5pt;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  border-radius: 10pt;
}

img:first-child {
  /*padding-left: 15pt;*/
  margin-left: auto;
}

img:last-child {
  /*padding-right: 100pt;*/
  margin-right: auto;
}

.images {
  background: orange;
  padding-left: 30pt;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-top: 15pt;
  margin-bottom: 15pt;
  height: 200pt;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.images:last-child::after {
  content: "";
  padding-right: 30pt;
} 

.images::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Since your images div doesn't have a defined width, you can not place a padding on the right,"* Okay. But why does padding on the left work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing nothing wrong. Apparently the combination of apply padding to a flex container with an overflow-x causes this unexpected behavior.

I checked your code and solved the problem by adding a parent div "container" with same paddings and margins than "images" div and I put "images" into  "container" and I set height and width to 100%.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <style>
        img {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 200pt;
            margin-left: 7.5pt;
            margin-right: 7.5pt;
            scroll-snap-align: center;
            border-radius: 10pt;
        }

        img:first-child {
            /*padding-left: 15pt;*/
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        img:last-child {
            /*padding-right: 100pt;*/
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .images {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: orange;
            scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            display: flex;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }

        .images::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
        .content{
            background: orange;
            margin-top: 15pt;
            margin-bottom: 15pt;
            padding-left: 30pt;
            padding-right: 30pt;
            height: 200pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%;">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="images">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80"/>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80"/>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80"/>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80"/>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80"/>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80"/>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80"/>
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594993082512-477197cedf34?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=676&q=80"/>
        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In this [blog](https://chenhuijing.com/blog/flexbox-and-padding/) there are two more ways that you can try and also there is more information about it.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for helping and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this seems to have the same problem as the solution proposed by Michael. In this: https://imgur.com/a/cbAujez notice how in first 2 pics of my original code, when scrolled, the pics scroll all the way to the left edges. But in 3rd pic when I use your way, it doesn't go into the edges and orange is visible. I need the pics to go all the way to the edges without any Orange when scrolled.