# react-indiana-drag-scroll the shadow of the last item not shown

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using react-indiana-drag-scroll, and I am doing a Horizontal scroll, but the last item ( the 30th) 's right red shadow cannot show on screen

I tried to add padding/ margin/ border, still does not work.

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-indiana-drag-scroll-default-forked-1xcxt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the issue of [react-indiana-drag-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-indiana-drag-scroll). It's the peculiarity of browsers behavior [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993170/last-margin-padding-collapsing-in-flexbox-grid-layout), [[2]](https://chenhuijing.com/blog/flexbox-and-padding/).

There are many different solutions to solve your exact problem.

Emulate margin by `:after` pseudo-element ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-indiana-drag-scroll-emulate-margin-hwefp?file=/styles.css)):

```css
.container:after {
   content: "";
   flex: 0 0 10px;
}
.row:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Use `inline-block` ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-indiana-drag-scroll-inline-block-0pner?file=/styles.css)):

```css
.container {
   display: block;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
.row {
   ...
   margin: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Other solutions could be found by the links above.